# Use WinAppDriver to select/highlight block of text

Tags: desktop-application, winappdriver

I'm currently implementing some proof-of-concept automated tests using Windows Application Driver for our Microsoft Word Plugin.

What I need to do is select (i.e. highlight) a block of text (i.e. an entire paragraph or a bullet point list) within a Word document then click on a button in our Plugin.

I can interacting with the plugin and the standard Word buttons easily enough, however i'm struggling to find a method that will allow me to select a block of text.

Has anyone got any imaginative solutions?